# Is it possible to extract the foreground in a video where the biggest part of the background is a huge screen (playing a video)?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, background-foreground

I am working on a multi-view telepresence project using an array of kinect cameras.
To improve the visual quality we want to extract the foreground, e.g. the person standing in the middle using the color image, the color image and not the depth image because we want to use the more reliable color image to repair some artefacts in the depth image.

The problem now is that the foreground objects (usually 1-2 persons) are standing in front of a huge screen showing another party, which is also moving all the time, of the telepresence system and this screen is visible for some of the kinects. Is it still possible to extract the foreground for these kinects and if so, could you point me in the right direction?

Some more information regarding the existing system:
we already have a system running that merges the depth maps of all the kinects, but that only gets us so far. There are a lot of issues with the kinect depth sensor, e.g. interference and distance to the sensor.
Also the color and depth sensor are slightly shifted, so when you map the color (like a texture) on a mesh reconstructed using the depth data you sometimes map the floor on the person.

All these issues decrease the overall quality of the depth data, but not the color data, so one could view the color image silhouette as the "real" one and the depth one as a "broken" one. But nevertheless the mesh is constructed using the depth data. So improving the depth data equals improving the quality of the system.
Now if you have the silhouette you could try to remove/modify incorrect depth values outside of the silhouette and/or add missing depth values inside

Thanks for every hint you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with this kind of problems the strategy you propose is *not* the best way to go.

As you have a non-constant background, the problem you want to solve is actually 2D segmentation. This is a hard problem, and people are typically using depth to make segmentation easier and not the other way round. I would try to combine / merge the multiple depth maps from your Kinects in order to improve your depth images, maybe in a [Kinect fusion](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/surfacerecon/) kind of way, or using classic [sensor fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion) techniques.

If you are absolutely determined to follow your strategy, you could try to use your imperfect depth maps to combine the RGB camera images of the Kinects in order to reconstruct a complete view of the background (without occlusion by the people in front of it). However, due to the changing background image on the screen, this would require your Kinects' RGB cameras to by synchronized, which I think is not possible.

**Edit in the light of comments / updates**

I think exploiting your knowledge of the image on the screen is your only chance of doing background subtraction for silhouette enhancement. I see that this is a tough problem as the sceen is a stereoscopic display, if I understand you correctly.

You could try to compute a model that describes what your Kinect RGB cameras see (given the stereoscopic display and their placement, type of sensor etc) when you display a certain image on your screen, essentially a function telling you: Kinect K sees `(r, g, b)` at pixel `(x, y)` when I show `(r',g',b')` at pixel `(x',y')` on my display. To do this you will have do create a sequence of calibration images which you show on the display, without a person standing in front of it, and film with the Kinect. This would allow you to predict the appearance of your screen in the Kinect cameras, and thus compute background subtraction. This is a pretty challenging task (but it would give a good research paper if it works).

**A side note:** You can easily compute the geometric relation of a Kinect's depth camera to its color camera, in order to avoid mapping the floor on the person. Some Kinect APIs allow you to retrieve the raw image of the depth camera. If you cover the IR projector you can film a calibration pattern with both, depth and RGB camera, and compute an extrinsic calibration.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

I modified my question to include some additional information.  
I think there are ways to synchronize the kinects, but not without a drastic framerate drop, so that is not feasible.  
Well, in theory I know what the display is showing, but it is multi-user stereo, so 4+ images on top of each other and the two parties of the telepresence are not synchronised, so that won't work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the updates! Thats an interesting and tough problem. I updated my answer - see whether it is more helpful now.